# Is there any Pythonic way to manipulate Dictionaries to follow DRY philosophy in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have got dictionary set of required queries as shown below:

```
[
    {
        "primary_attribute__name": "Color"
        "primary_attr_values__name": "Red",
    },
    {
        "primary_attribute__name": "Color",
        "primary_attr_values__name": "Green",
    },
]
```

Now I want :

```
[
    {
        "primary_attribute__name": "Color"
        {
            "primary_attr_values__name": "Red",
            "primary_attr_values__name": "Green",
            "primary_attr_values__name": "Yellow",
        },
    }
]
```

Or is this good approach:

```
primary_attribute = {
    "Color": {
        "primary_attr_values__name": [
            "red",
            "green",
            "yellow",
        ]
    }
}
```

How it can be achieved?

**Edit:**
Actually I have  Product, Product has Variant and each Variant may have VariantAttributes. VariantAttributes has primary_attr, primary_aatr_value ( these are like color: green, color:red, color:green)

For that Product;  ProductVariant's  ProductAttribute primary_attr_name will be same, for example : Color, but the values will be different on each variant. I am trying to solve this condition with dictionary.

Comment: The thing you "want" is not valid Python syntax (beside the missing quote, it looks like a mix between a list and a dict), so it's really hard to tell what the actual format you want is.

Comment: The second code fragment makes no sense: the keys in a dictionary are unique, so you can not list the same key twice or more.

Comment: Instead of an "edit: actually I have..." please just _show_ what you actually have?

Comment: You're still not quite telling us what you want here. (Also, why "primary attribute" and "secondary attribute"? Why is a "variant" a relation to an "attribute"?)

Comment: @AKX I hope the edited question is now sufficient to describe what I wanted for

Comment: I'm not following how that "dictionary pattern" relates to the Django query and models you've posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somewhat hard to tell what you really want here, but if my guess is correct...

Given data like you have, if you want to group it to an attribute -> values mapping, it's easy to do with a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [
    {
        "primary_attribute__name": "Color",
        "primary_attr_values__name": "Red",
    },
    {
        "primary_attribute__name": "Color",
        "primary_attr_values__name": "Green",
    },
    {
        "primary_attribute__name": "Color",
        "primary_attr_values__name": "Blue",
    },
    {
        "primary_attribute__name": "Shape",
        "primary_attr_values__name": "Circle",
    },
    {
        "primary_attribute__name": "Shape",
        "primary_attr_values__name": "Rectangle",
    },
]

attribute_values = defaultdict(list)

for datum in data:
    attr_name = datum["primary_attribute__name"]
    attr_value = datum["primary_attr_values__name"]
    attribute_values[attr_name].append(attr_value)

print(dict(attribute_values))
```

This outputs

```
{'Color': ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'], 'Shape': ['Circle', 'Rectangle']}
```

Comment: It seems to work for me, how can I pass primary_attribute__name and primary_attr_values__name on template?

I Tried  context['attributes'] = dict(attribute_values) on views and  {{context.attributes}} in template, I am getting
 defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Color': ['Red', 'Red']})

I think I am close to the solution

Comment: A defaultdict behaves just like a dict, so in a template you'd use it just like a dict; `{% for attr, values in context.attributes.items() %}...`